# How do I prevent a ribbon/path from "crossing over" in d3?

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js, svg, intersection

I'm creating a ribbon from an outer pie chart to an inner pie chart with the following logic:

1. Start from `outer_pie.start_angle` and draw a circular arc to `outer_pie.end_angle` (tracing the inner arc of the outer pie chart)
2. Draw a Bezier Curve to the `inner_pie.end_angle` with a 2 control points
3. The first control point is the same as the starting point (ie "no bend")
4. The second control point is a constant radius longer than the inner pie's radius (let's call this `cp_2`)
5. Draw a circular arc to the `inner_pie.start_angle` (tracing the outer arc of the inner pie chart)
6. Lastly draw the final Bezier Curve to the `outer_pie.start_angle` (starting point in step 1) with 2 control points
7. The first control point is the same as step 4 (let's call this `cp_1`)
8. The second control point is the same as step 3

The problem right now is `cp_1` and `cp_2` are both constant and the ribbon "crosses" depending on the values of the following:

- `pie_outer.start_angle`
- `pie_outer.end_angle`
- `pie_outer.r`
- `pie_inner.start_angle`
- `pie_inner.end_angle`
- `pie_inner.r`
- `pie_inner.cx`
- `pie_inner.cy`

So I need some crazy mathematical formula (or some recursive function) to adjust `cp_1` and `cp_2` until the ribbons don't cross and look "nice".

Note that the inner pie charts will always be inside the outer pie chart.

The problems:

[image]
[image]

Not a problem:

[image]